# How to extract data on-fly from the argument with boost::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Say you are passing a function to a function:

```
foo(boost::bind( &CLASS_NAME::OnValueChanged, this, _1));
```

But the problem is `_1` type can vary, I don't need it really, only a data of it. So I would like to write something like this:

```
foo(boost::bind( &CLASS_NAME::OnValueChanged, this, _1.GetName()));
```

because no matter what type `_1` is, I know that every time it has `GetName()` method, and the outcome type is the same (`wstring`).

How to do it?

*Additionally in my case, the type holding `GetName` is a template.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need another bind!

```
foo(boost::bind( &CLASS_NAME::OnValueChanged, this, boost::bind(GetNameFunctor(), _1));
```

A general purpose implementation of GetNameFunctor() would look like e.g.

```
struct GetNameFunctor {
     typedef std::string result_type;

     template <typename T> std::string operator()(T const& o) const {
         return o.GetName();
     }
};
```

If you want more control/support here you could have a look at

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to do it with lambda (I mean, getting the name)? I would prefer keeping the code as close to execution as possible.

Comment: Assuming you mean c++11 lambdas, yes IFF your classes share a polymorphic base. Otherwise, you need polymorphic lambdas (c++14) which are actually syntactic sugar for something like `GetNameFunctor` shown. (If you meant _`Boost Lambda`_ then, yes, you can, but I wouldn't recommend mixing with Boost Bind.)

Comment: `_1` does not change per call, I have several `foo`s and they change from `foo1`, `foo2`, to `fooN`. I meant C++11 lambdas, could you please share the code?

Comment: `boost::bind([](MyFixedType const& o) { return o.GetName(); }, _1)`. Depending on your platform/compiler you may need to `#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE`. Honestly, in this case you probably just would use `std::memfn(&MyFixedType::GetName)` or the `bind`. I think it's more readable

Comment: Thank you very much. I ended up with functor, because even if I put this define at the top of my ".cpp" file, compiler still complained about missing `result_type` in inner bind. Btw. what do you mean by "or the bind", I am using bind?

Comment: Exactly. You are now. You wanted to use lambdas, but they'd just end up being more verbose, I think

Comment: In C++14 you could do `foo([this](auto&& o) { return OnValueChanged(o.GetName()); });`